# Почему не работает ajax в wordpress: открытие поста в модальном окне?

Tags: php, wordpress, ajax

У меня такая проблема. Я пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы все посты, которые выводятся на главной странице через цикл открывались не в новом окне, а в модальном окне из bootstrap. Проблема в том, что почему-то работает не совсем так, как хотелось бы - не работает. Модальное-то окно оно открывает, но пустое, без статьи. Вот как все работает:
в *functions.php* я поместил вот такой код:

```php
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'data_fetch');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'data_fetch');
function data_fetch($postID){
    $postID=intval( $_POST['param'] );

    $args = array(
    ‘p’ => $postID, // ID of a page, post, or custom type
    //’post_type’ => ‘any’
    );
    $recent = new WP_Query($args);
    while ( $recent->have_posts() ) : $recent->the_post();?>
        <div class=»modal-header»>
        <button type=»button» class=»close» data-dismiss=»modal» aria-label=»Close»><span aria-hidden=»true»>&times;</span></button>
        <?php the_title( '<h2 class=»modal-title text-center»>', '</h5>' ); ?>
        </div>
        <div class=»modal-content»>
        <div class=»conterer″>
            <img src=»<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>» class=»instaupp-img img-circle»>
        </div>
            <div class=»conterer″>
                <p><i>Описание</i></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php
    die();
}
```

Затем, в *index.php* я сделал вот это:

```php
<?php query_posts('cat=2');
        $args = array(
          'p' => $postID, // ID поста
          'post_type' => 'any'
          );
          $recent = new WP_Query($args);
                                    ?>
        <?php if (have_posts()) :  while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="oneNew p1" style="background-image: url(img/newBg.png)">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-xl" data-ajax-param="<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_title( '<h2 class="modal-title text-center">', '</h2>' ); ?></a>                      
          </div>    
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

А так же в этом же *index.php* скрипт:

```html
<script>
function fetch(e){var param = $(e.target).attr('data-ajax-param');
 // поиск id поста
  $.post('wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', {'action':'my_action', 'param':param}, function(response){
   $('.modal-content.ajax').html(response);
});
}
</script>
<script>
$( '[data-ajax-param]' ).click(function (e) {
 fetch(e);
});
</script>
```

Ну, и в *footer.php* html-верстка этого самого модального окна:

```html
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-xl modal-content.ajax" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myExtraLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
    <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"></h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      ... <div class="conterer">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

По нажатию на новость открывается модальное окно, но пустое, без всего. Где может быть ошибка или не так где-то что-то работает? Спасибо

Comment: А в чем может быть проблема? Я могу прислать еще код. Может, я в functions.php написал запрос не туда? Я поставил его в самом конце, после `/**
 * Load Jetpack compatibility file.
 */
if ( defined( 'JETPACK__VERSION' ) ) {
 require get_template_directory() . '/inc/jetpack.php';
}`

Comment: Ну, например, нет у вас такого элемента с двумя классами `modal-content ajax` а вы туда пытаетесь писать html.

Comment: @KAGGDesign Признаю свою ошибку, был неправ, потому удалил свой ответ.

Comment: @АнатолийТоторов Еще момент, у вас в php-коде что-то с кавычками, кажется вы смогли использовать все виды, так быть не должно.

Comment: @Neolot все могут ошибаться, не все способны признать свои ошибки )

Comment: @Neolot кавычки нужно заменить на обычные - ""?

Comment: @KAGGDesign у меня есть в html коде модального окна вот такой класс - modal-content.ajax. Такое недопустимо?

Comment: @АнатолийТоторов Да, я сам заменил кавычки, возьмите здесь обновленный код https://pastebin.com/vHGwwzsL

Comment: Классы не могут иметь точку в названии.

Comment: @Neolot Спасибо! я использовал ваш код. Но, проблема, я так понимаю, не только в этом.

Comment: @KAGGDesign а, значит, ошибка где-то здесь? а что тогда поменять нужно?

Comment: @KAGGDesign я убрал точку. теперь это два класса. modal-content и ajax. Теперь вроде как в окне выводит заголовок новости, на которую я кликаю, но это окно почему-то открывается где-то в низу, где, собственно, html код модального окна и находится.

Comment: Вопрос плавно перетёк в сторону css )) Модальные окна должны быть с position:fixed

Comment: @KAGGDesign у меня модальное окно из bootstrap, я в его css вообще не заглядывал

Comment: @АнатолийТоторов Результат ajax-запроса должен вставляться в `<div class="modal-body"></div>`, но у вас в шаблоне такого элемента нет. Замените `... <div class="conterer">` на `<div class="modal-body">`. Соответственно, в js `$('.modal-content.ajax').html(response);` нужно заменить на `$('.modal-body').html(response);`

Comment: @Neolot я заменил, теперь работает вот так: когда я нажимаю на новость, то страницу скроллит до модального окна, которое открывается внизу, именно там, где и вставлен html-код модального окна, хотя должно открываться по центру страницы

Comment: @Neolot о! вроде работает! Я изменил html-код модального окна в footer.php вот этот код: `<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-xl modal-content" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myExtraLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
    <div class="modal-content ajax">`, то есть, у div'а с классом modal fade я убрал класс ajax и подписал этот класс ajax к div'у с классом modal-content. И теперь все открывается. А возможно как-то сделать так, чтобы в адресной строке была еще ссылка на это модальное окно с новостью?

Comment: @АнатолийТоторов Спокойной ночи, Анатолий)